# IOS10.2 can't download apps

Tags: applications

Ok so I want to get some more games like five nights at freddys sister location but the get button is greyed out and it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 1):

That might be because restrictions are enabled. To disable them, follow these steps.

1. Tap the 'Settings' icon
2. Select 'General'
3. Tap 'Restrictions'
4. In the 'Allowed Content' section, tap Apps
5. In the 'Allow Apps Rated' section, tap Allow All Apps

Source: [stan.com](https://help.stan.com.au/hc/en-us/articles/203780194-The-GET-button-is-greyed-out-or-disabled-in-the-Apple-App-Store)